# How to create sequential transaction numbers with the serial number of each transaction in the MS ACCESS database in Dapper with VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, dapper

How to create sequential transaction numbers with the serial number of each transaction in the MS ACCESS database in Dapper with VB.NET?.
Is it possible to reset the serial number to `00001` if the month changes?.

Maybe the code I posted is still wrong. Please Guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private HeaderInvno As Integer
    Dim sis As New Stocksinservice()
    Private Sub CreateInvno()
        Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim strTime As String = myDate.ToString("MMyy-")
        Dim Stockin = sis.SelectTop()
        If Stockin Is Nothing Then
            HeaderInvno = 1
        Else
            HeaderInvno = Stockin.HeaderInvno + 1
        End If
        If ComboBox1.Text = "ITEM TRANSFER IN" Then
            BtxtInvoNo.Text = "DEPT-ITI-" & strTime & (HeaderInvno).ToString("00000")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "PURCHASE INVOICE" Then
            BtxtInvoNo.Text = "DEPT-PI-" & strTime & (HeaderInvno).ToString("00000")
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "RECEIVE ITEM" Then
            BtxtInvoNo.Text = "DEPT-RI-" & strTime & (HeaderInvno).ToString("00000")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        CreateInvno()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stocksinservice
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DEMO.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Public Function SelectTop() As Stocksin
        Dim sql = $"SELECT TOP 1 HeaderInvno FROM Stocksin ORDER BY HeaderInvno DESC"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocksin)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
Public Class Stocksin
    Public Property Invno() As String
    Public Property HeaderInvno() As Integer
End Class
```

Table `Stocksin`

This is a stored database record

| Invno | HeaderInvno | InvnoDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DEPT-ITI-1023-00001 | 1 | 18-10-2023 |

So if I select from the combobox the result is something like below :

```
DEPT-ITI-1023-00002
DEPT-PI-1023-00002
DEPT-RI-1023-00002
```

The desired result should be like below:

```
DEPT-ITI-1023-00002
DEPT-PI-1023-00001
DEPT-RI-1023-00001
```

Comment: _Is it possible to reset the serial number to 00001 if the month changes_ is this really critically important to you? One of the points of a serial number is that it is unique. If you reset the serial number every month then you need to also know that month and year in order to make it unique

Comment: It's actually easier to just use an Autonumber in a table, a number that increments forever, then add some calcs to the record to make it look like with you want.

Comment: @Nick.Mc , `If you reset the serial number every month then you need to also know that month and year in order to make it unique ` for this we can find out from `InvnoDate`

Comment: @Nick.Mc , `It's actually easier to just use an Autonumber in a table, a number that increments forever, then add some calcs to the record to make it look like with you want.` 
If I use autonumber then I can't create a sequential serial number for each transaction

Comment: You can write a query that works it out after the fact. i.e. Sep 2023 has ids from 300 to 430, Oct 2023 has ids from 431 to 560. You just subtract 430 from the Oct 2023 Id's and you have a serial number that starts from one

Comment: You can add column `MonthYear` for example to store MMyy. If it's not equal, you can reset `HeaderInvno` to 1. And you can add column , let's say `SmartCode` to store `DEPT-ITI` etc, so it can store different running number per `SmartCode`

Comment: Attaching serial number formats to real world things is a _bad_ idea. Because the real world changes and suddenly all of your serial numbers don't make sense.... like do you ever expect more than 99999 transactions in a month? If you just have a "proper" infinitely incrementing serial number behind the scenes, it will cover everything, you can decide how to format it after the fact. The other question is someone just after this because it looks neat or because it is actually required by your business process?

Comment: Generating custom unique identifier is a common topic. Are you concerned about gaps in sequence? This sequential number can be calculated when needed. One way is on a report using Sorting & Grouping and textbox RunningSum property. However, if you must save to table, review https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Comment: Are you just resetting it because you don't want to hit 99999? Cause you could just have an infinitely incresaing number and just take the last 5 digits and you'd have the same result - a unique number per month (except it wouldn't reset to 00001 for a long time)

Comment: Have you done any debugging such as stepping through code?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan , `You can add column MonthYear for example to store MMyy. If it's not equal, you can reset HeaderInvno to 1. And you can add column , let's say SmartCode to store DEPT-ITI etc,` Thank you for your reply, can you please reply with the answer

Comment: @June7 , `Have you done any debugging such as stepping through code?` 
For the transaction sequence, this is the problem: just select top of one column, then automatically every subsequent transaction will be in the same serial number

Comment: Get the top record from the db and include the `InvnoDate` field. If the query returns `Nothing` OrElse `Now.Year > InvnoDate.Year` OrElse `Now.Month > InvnoDate.Month` Then, `HeaderInvno = 1` Else `HeaderInvno = Stockin.HeaderInvno + 1`.

Comment: @dr.null , thank you for your response . 
From your code suggestion it looks like this `If stockin Is Nothing OrElse myDate.Year > stockin.InvnoDate.Year OrElse myDate.Month > stockin.InvnoDate.Month Then` and  according to the answer below, I just need to change the code line from `If Not newMonthYear.Equals(CurrentMonthYear) Then` to `If stockin Is Nothing OrElse myDate.Year > stockin.InvnoDate.Year OrElse myDate.Month > stockin.InvnoDate.Month Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add column here (adjust it with your code). We need additional  column to contain smart code on `ItemTransferIn` and check `MonthYear`

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD COLUMN ItemTransferIn VARCHAR(255),
ADD COLUMN MonthYear VARCHAR(6);
```

Update select method by having conditional parameter for `ItemTransferIn` when select top, and then update if month changed.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private HeaderInvno As Integer
    Private CurrentMonthYear As String
    Dim sis As New Stocksinservice()
    Private ItemTransferIn As String ' Define ItemTransferIn as a string

    Private Sub CreateInvno()
        Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim strTime As String = myDate.ToString("yyMM-")
        Dim newMonthYear As String = myDate.ToString("yyMM")

        ' Set ItemTransferIn based on ComboBox1.Text
        If ComboBox1.Text = "ITEM TRANSFER IN" Then
            ItemTransferIn = "DEPT-ITI-"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "PURCHASE INVOICE" Then
            ItemTransferIn = "DEPT-PI-"
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "RECEIVE ITEM" Then
            ItemTransferIn = "DEPT-RI-"
        End If

        ' Retrieve the HeaderInvno and MonthYear from the database
        Dim stockin = sis.SelectTop(ItemTransferIn )
        If stockin IsNot Nothing Then
            HeaderInvno = stockin.HeaderInvno
            CurrentMonthYear = stockin.MonthYear
        Else
            HeaderInvno = 0
            CurrentMonthYear = ""
        End If

        ' Check if the month and year have changed
        Dim newMonthYear As String = myDate.ToString("yyMM")
        If Not newMonthYear.Equals(CurrentMonthYear) Then
            HeaderInvno = 1
            CurrentMonthYear = newMonthYear
            ' Update the MonthYear in the database
            sis.UpdateMonthYear(CurrentMonthYear, ItemTransferIn )
        Else
            HeaderInvno += 1
        }

        ' Concatenate ItemTransferIn with other parts of the invoice number
        BtxtInvoNo.Text = ItemTransferIn & strTime & HeaderInvno.ToString("00000")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        CreateInvno()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And another `Stocksinservice` class

```
Public Class Stocksinservice
    Private connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DEMO.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    
    Public Function SelectTop(itemTransferIn As String) As Stocksin
        Dim sql = "SELECT TOP 1 HeaderInvno, MonthYear FROM Stocksin WHERE ItemTransferIn = @ItemTransferIn ORDER BY HeaderInvno DESC"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Return _conn.Query(Of Stocksin)(sql, New With {Key .ItemTransferIn = itemTransferIn}).FirstOrDefault()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Sub UpdateMonthYear(monthYear As String, itemTransferIn As String)
        Dim sql = "UPDATE YourTableName SET MonthYear = @MonthYear WHERE ItemTransferIn = @ItemTransferIn" ' Replace YourTableName with the actual table name
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            _conn.Execute(sql, New With {Key .MonthYear = monthYear, .ItemTransferIn = itemTransferIn})
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your perfect answer and sorry I was late in replying. 
Maybe you need to fix a few lines in the line code a little `missing Check if the month and year have changed for code Dim newMonthYear As String = myDate.ToString("yyMM") double variable, missing end if and remove }` and for this code `sis.UpdateMonthYear(CurrentMonthYear, ItemTransferIn)` 
I don't think it's necessary because in the end the transaction will be inserted into the database table. But I think your answer is perfect.

Comment: I made the latest post still related to your answer, maybe you can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77320701/how-to-handle-sequential-transaction-numbers-that-were-previously-deleted-so-the)